# A better alternative to the paired bar chart

Tags: visualization, charts

In an nice blog post about the [horrors of the paired bar chart](http://policyviz.com/killing-the-paired-bar-chart/), Jonathan Schwabish proposes an elegant alternative, as follows. Instead of having pairs of yellow and blue bars, simply plot their endpoints, connected by a thin grey line, like in this plot of [Gini coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) before and after tax:

[image]

For those who want to go full Tufte, there is even this:

[image]

It seems to me that there should be a way to modify `BarChart` to do this -- haven't been able to figure out how. Does anyone have any ideas about how to produce a plot like the first of the two plots above (or the second, for that matter)? Notice that these are categorical data.

Here are the data used in these graphs:

```
giniCoefficients =
 {{"United States", 4.2, 5.7},
  {"Israel", 4.1, 5.8},
  {"UK", 4.1, 6.3},
  {"Canada", 3.8, 5.5},
  {"Greece", 3.8, 6.0},
  {"Spain", 3.8, 5.7},
  {"Australia", 3.8, 5.5},
  {"Norway", 3.7, 5.7},
  {"Korea", 3.7, 4.4},
  {"Poland", 3.6, 6.5},
  {"Taiwan", 3.6, 4.2},
  {"Germany", 3.6, 6.0},
  {"Finland", 3.5, 5.8},
  {"Ireland", 3.5, 6.3},
  {"Slovak Republic", 3.5, 5.4},
  {"Japan", 3.5, 4.9},
  {"Austria", 3.3, 5.5},
  {"Netherlands", 3.3, 5.7},
  {"Sweden", 3.3, 5.7},
  {"Denmark", 3.3, 5.6},
  {"Luxemberg", 3.2, 5.2},
  {"Switzerland", 3.1, 4.7}
 }
```

Comment: Why not just use Graphics and Text?

Comment: Yes, that would be straightforward enough. I was frustrated that I couldn't hack BarChart to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a version that builds up the "full Tufte" version of the plot presented above by building up the corresponding `Graphics` primitives. Quite a few styling decisions must be made with respect to colors, spacings, overall aspect ratio of the plot, etc. I went with choices that were aesthetically pleasing to me, but of course it should be relatively easy to tweak those within the function.

The **vertical sorting** of the data points is also somewhat arbitrary. At this point the data is presented in such a way that the points with lowest first Gini coefficient show up at the bottom, and in the case of a tie, they are ordered by the alphabetical order of their labels (because of the way `SortBy` works). If that is undesirable, one should adjust the sorting function in `SortBy`: for instance, a stable sort such as `SortBy[{#[[2]]&}]` would leave tied elements in the original order in which they were present in the dataset, etc.

The **horizontal `PlotRange`** is adjusted somewhat automatically to include the labels as well by including an asymmetric `PlotRangePadding` in the $x$ direction. This is somewhat brittle because the length of the label strings is never taken into explicit consideration. I have the impression that there should be a combination of PlotRange / Padding / Clipping that could take care of that automatically, but at this moment it slips my mind.

```
fullTufte[dataset_] :=
 Graphics[
  Flatten@MapIndexed[
    Function[{item, index},
     {
      (*heading*)
      Black, Text[item[[1]], {item[[2]] - 0.35, First@index}, {1, 0}],
      (*line*)
      Gray, Line[{{item[[2]], First@index}, {item[[3]], First@index}}],
      (*numbers*)
      Darker@Blue, 
      Inset[item[[2]], {item[[2]], First@index}, {0, 0}, Background -> White],
      Orange, Inset[item[[3]], {item[[3]], First@index}, {0, 0}, Background -> White]
      }
     ],
    SortBy[#[[2]] &][dataset]
    ],
  PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.3], Scaled[0.05]}, Automatic},
  AspectRatio -> 1.6,
  Axes -> {True, False}
 ]
```

Here is the result of its application to the `giniCoefficients` dataset:

```
fullTufte[giniCoefficients]
```

[image: graphics result]

Comment: What a great function -- thank you! It's really beautiful. I'd love to see this style of plot replace paired bar charts more generally. I can think of relatively few cases where a paired bar chart is preferable. In some cases, when you want to really focus on the density of the bars themselves, the form used in Mathematica's `PairedBarChart`, with the bars on opposites of a central axis, may be acceptable. The obvious example is a [population pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_pyramid).

Answer (score 6):

In version 10+ there is `NumberLinePlot` that can be used for this.

```
NumberLinePlot[Interval[Rest@#] & /@ Reverse[giniCoefficients, 1], 
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[#, Thin, PointSize[Large]] & /@ {Orange, 
     Blue}),
 PlotRange -> {{2, Automatic}, Automatic},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
 Epilog -> 
  MapIndexed[
   Function[{item, index}, 
    Inset[First@item, {item[[2]] - .05, First@index}, {1, 0}]], 
   Reverse[giniCoefficients, 1], 1]]
```

[image]

There are a couple of things that I don't know how to do that I'd like to be able to without a `ReplaceAll` hack on the plot.

1. Find the length of the text in the graphic so a proper lower `PlotRange` can be set.
2. Define a `PlotStyle` that gives either of the styles the OP requested.

Hopefully someone will add an answer with those features.

Comment: I'll just add that I tried to used `Labeled` on the `Interval`s but it was ignored in the plot. I think that would be a nice feature to have for `NumberLinePlot` since it is a line and the named positions for `Labeled` would work well for it. If there are any WRI eyes crossing this.

Answer (score 3):

### RangeBarChart

With a custom `ChartElementFunction` we can use the built-in (undocumented) function `` Charting`RangeBarChart `` as follows:

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF[marker_: "Point"] := Module[{coords = Reverse /@ Thread[{Mean[#2], #}] & @@ #}, 
  {CapForm["Round"], Line[coords], PointSize[.02], 
   If[marker === "Point", {Blue, Point[coords[[1]]], Orange, Point[coords[[2]]]}, 
    {Text[Style[#[[1]], Blue, 12, Background -> White], #] &@ coords[[1]], 
     Text[Style[#[[1]], Orange, 12, Background -> White], #] &@ coords[[2]]}]}] &;

labeleddata = Labeled[{##2}, Style[ToString[#]<>"   ", 16], Before]&@@@ giniCoefficients;
options = {ChartElementFunction -> ceF[], BarOrigin -> Left, AspectRatio -> 1,
  Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Scaled[.05], Scaled[.05]}}};

Panel[Quiet @ Charting`RangeBarChart[labeleddata, options]]
```

[image]

Change `ceF[]` to `ceF[blah]` in `options` to get

[image]